# onViewableItemsChanged doesn't fire after unmounting then remounting

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-native-flatlist

I have a component that looks like this;

```
const ComponentA = () => {
.....
const [values, setValues] = useState({});
const handleData = (data: any) => {
    const newData = { ...data };
    setValues(newData);
};

return (
......
  <ComponentB
    someData={someData}
  />
.....
 );
};
```

In this component values are used as prop for another child component.

Now the ComponentB looks like this;

```
const ComponentB = () => {
.....
const list = useRef<FlatList>(null);

const handleViewableItemsChange = useRef(
({ viewableItems }: any) => {setViewable(viewableItems);
});

const renderList = useCallback(() => {
 return (
  <FlatList
   ....
   keyExtractor={(item, index) => getKeys(item, index)}
   ref={list}
   onViewableItemsChanged={handleViewableItemsChange.current}
  />
 );
}, [....]);

return (
   .....
   renderList()}
   .....
 );
};
```

I use handleViewableItemsChange to check the viewable in the list so I can render additional stuff.

When this is first rendered everything works fine. handleViewableItemsChange gets fired and I set the viewable correctly.

However if I Change the state in ComponentA, then goBack to another screen, then come to this screen again, handleViewableItemsChange doesn't get fired.

If I don't change the state in ComponentA and do it everything works fine.

I've tried so many things but handleViewableItemsChange only fires again after remounting if I get rid of this code;

```
const [values, setValues] = useState({});
const handleData = (data: any) => {
    const newData = { ...data };
    setValues(newData);
};
```

But I need that state change.
Any ideas why this is happening?